# How to find original matrix from eigenbasis and eigenvalues?

Tags: matrix-representation

I'm not sure is it the right place to ask this but, I think it is better to ask here than Math Overflow. It is about how to find the matrix representation of an operator (for the CHSH test).

> What are the matrices that has $\left|\frac{\pi}{8}\right>$ and $\left|\frac{5 \pi}{8}\right>$ with eigenvalues $\{1,-1\}$?

I can relate an operator with eigenbasis geometrically, but I do not know how to represent the operator matrix using these eigenbases and eigenvalues.

Comment: FYI there are two stack exchange sites for mathematics. MathOverflow is dedicated to mathematics research questions whereas Mathematics is for general math questions.

Comment: Generally, I'd recommend asking this on the [Maths SE](https://math.stackexchange.com) but it's been answered here and is at least semi-relevant, so I see no point in migrating it (unless @user13783 wants it migrated)

Answer (score 4):

$$
\left|\frac{\pi}{8}\right\rangle\left\langle\frac{\pi}{8}\right|-\left|\frac{5\pi}{8}\right\rangle\left\langle\frac{5\pi}{8}\right|
$$

Answer (score 2):

Any normal matrix $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and respective eigenvectors $|u_i\rangle$ can be writen as
$$
A = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i |u_i\rangle\langle u_i|.
$$
This is called spectral decomposition.

*Note that a matrix is normal if $AA^\dagger=A^\dagger A$ holds. Hermitian and unitary matrices are special cases of normal ones.*

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct. A normal matrix is *unitarily* diagonalisable. General diagonalisable matrices are of the form $A=MDM^{-1}$ where $M$ is invertible but can be non-unitary. In other words: it can be diagonal in a non-orthonormal basis. The spectral decomposition also only holds for normal matrices (general diagonalisable matrices are not of that form).

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich: Thank you for the comment, you are right. Just edited the answer.